# Permanently disable "beep" with volume change?

Tags: macos, mac, sound-volume

Is there a way to permanently disable the "beeping" sound following volume changes?

Just in case, I use a Macbook Air with OSX 10.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sytstem Pref -> Sound -> **Uncheck** Play Feedback when volume is changed 
[image]